# Multilinguale website with unique content

Tags: wordpress, seo, multilingual

I'm building a website called "Toolbox" (http://toolbox.appizy.com) which aims at sharing calculations tools. It's basically a Youtube-like for calculation tools. This website is build with Wordpress.

I’m facing an interesting situation:

- The website should be multi-lingual, meaning that everyone has the interface in his language;
- The content (the calculations tools) is brought by the user of the platform (like Youtube). This content is unique on the website and won’t be translated.

My questions are the following:

- Do you have any idea of WP plugin that aims at choosing/proposing the language based on user browser or user previous choice (with a cookie for example) and not on URL (like .com/en or .com/de)?
- Is this approach compatible with a good SEO?

Thanks by advance for any advice.

Nicolas

Comment: Not the answer, but I would not recommend Wordpress for a multilingual website. Drupal for example can handle that much better. If you show the same url in different languages you can confuse google, which is not so good for SEO.

Comment: Ok.I come from Drupal and moved to WP. Maybe it's time to go back ! Thanks for the advice. Concerning same URL for both language, how do you explain Youtube way of working. On Youtube home page, you can change the language (bottom of page) : it doesn't change the content or the URL. Just auxiliary info are translated.

Comment: Can't explain it. But since YouTube belongs too Google...
But how would Google be able to properly index you content, you have different content under the same link?

Comment: No I have the same content but the "interface informations" should be in the language the user. For exemple, on Youtube you can watch videos in English but if you're French you have "Vue" instead of "View"

Comment: I just deployed a version of Drupal 7.23 and this works "out of the box". Still amazed by the power of this tool.

Comment: Ok, so I guess we have a solution :-)